# Why does iOS7 icons show black margin?

Tags: ios7

The last issue after update muy project to iOS7 is about iPhone icon, 
I use image.xcassets folder with no warnings, all seems to be fine but:

My real icon is:

[image]

and I see:

[image]

before, with iOs6, these black margins were not visible.

How can i get rid of those black margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a transparent margin. Let's say that if you put a transparent icon, the background color of the view where your icon is put is black.

Comment: Ok, thanks i'll try to remove transparent margin color and will tell you how it goes

Comment: It works perfectly, when I resized for iOS7 icons i forgot to fill transparent margin with white color. Thanks

Comment: Accept answer if it was correct. That may help other users with same kind of question to see faster that the problem was solved and not in suspend.

Comment: ...I accepted, I gave you +1 in Answer, what do you refer to?